# Size image with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to size my image using a CSS grid.
This is my CSS Code:

```
/* General */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/background.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Grid */
.grid-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
}
/* Menu-Logged-Out */
.menu-logged-out {
    grid-column: 3 / 11;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.menu-logged-out img {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover
}
```

And the following is my HTML code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>asd</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='/assets/css/header.css'>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Grid -->
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="menu-logged-out">
        <img src="#####">
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

But the image overflows my CSS grid, and it looks something like this:

[image]

How could I fix that?

Greetings
Dominik :)

Comment: Not sure what's the end goal here, you have a 12x12 Grid, but one child containing an image which you want to span the whole grid ? Is that it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed several properties, I believe this is what you want

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Grid */
.grid-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 8.5%);
}
/* Menu-Logged-Out */
.menu-logged-out {
    grid-column: 3 / 11;
    grid-row: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.menu-logged-out img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="menu-logged-out">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
</div>
```